# JS Apply custom style on click on a div and remove styling from the other one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got 2 toggles of 50% width and on click it show a div below 100% and hide the other one, vice-versa.

The function that make this possible works fine, but what i am looking to do, is add custom style on the toggle displayed

Here is what it should looks like at the end :
[The div one is displayed automatically with the custom style border black, thickker width bottom and text color black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiysW.png)

Here is what is does look now :[This is the style i would like when not openend, but i would like to change as i said the border and color style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAVrg.png)

`

```js
function switch_div(show) {  
  document.getElementById("show_"+show).style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("show_"+((show==1)?2:1)).style.display = "none";
}

function stylish(){
document.getElementById("borderRight").setAttribute(
   "style", "color:#000000;border:1px solid black;border-bottom:5px solid black;");
  
  document.getElementById("buttonRight").style.color = "#000000";
}
   function stylish2(){
document.getElementById("borderLeft").setAttribute(
   "style", "color:#000000;border:1px solid black;border-bottom:5px solid black;");
       document.getElementById("buttonLeft").style.color = "#000000";
   }
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  margin-top:3%;
}
  

.hide {
  display: none;
}

  .align1{
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #c3c6c6;
   cursor:pointer;
    
  }
  #borderRight{
    border-right:0px;
  }
  .titres{
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
     padding-top:2.3%;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#a2a2a4;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:1.5px;
   cursor:pointer;
    
  }

  .titres:hover{
    color:#000000;  
  }
```

```html
<div id="borderRight" class="align1" onclick="switch_div(1);">
          <button id="buttonRight" class="titres" onclick="stylish()">Description</button>
    </div><div id="borderLeft"class="align1"onclick="switch_div(2);"><button id="buttonLeft" class="titres" onclick="stylish2()">
          Additional information</button>
     </div>

<div class="content" id="show_1">
  Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
</div>

<div class="content hide" id="show_2">
  Div number 2
</div>
```

`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Uae active or fucus method on css its easy

Comment: @Dario added anwser, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  stylish();
});

function switch_div(show) {  
  document.getElementById("show_"+show).style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("show_"+((show==1)?2:1)).style.display = "none";
}

function stylish(){
document.getElementById("borderLeft").removeAttribute('style');
document.getElementById("borderRight").setAttribute(
   "style", "color:#000000;border:1px solid black;border-bottom:5px solid black;");
  
  document.getElementById("buttonRight").style.color = "#000000";
}
   function stylish2(){
   document.getElementById("borderRight").removeAttribute('style');
document.getElementById("borderLeft").setAttribute(
   "style", "color:#000000;border:1px solid black;border-bottom:5px solid black;");
       document.getElementById("buttonLeft").style.color = "#000000";
   }
```

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  margin-top:3%;
}
  

.hide {
  display: none;
}

  .align1{
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #c3c6c6;
   cursor:pointer;
    
  }
  #borderRight{
    border-right:0px;
  }
  .titres{
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
     padding-top:2.3%;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#a2a2a4;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing:1.5px;
   cursor:pointer;
    
  }

  .titres:hover{
    color:#000000;  
  }
```

```html
<div id="borderRight" class="align1" onclick="switch_div(1);">
          <button id="buttonRight" class="titres" onclick="stylish()">Description</button>
    </div><div id="borderLeft"class="align1"onclick="switch_div(2);"><button id="buttonLeft" class="titres" onclick="stylish2()">
          Additional information</button>
     </div>

<div class="content" id="show_1">
  Show by default (and when button 1 is clicked)
</div>

<div class="content hide" id="show_2">
  Div number 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it's fine ! i'll just adjust the text color , but the result is fine, took me hours to find a way, thanks a lot ! Wish you a nice day !

Comment: glad to help you, have a nice day )